# How can I replace parts of an included PDF file?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, text-manipulation

I'm using `pdflatex` and `\epsfig{file=img.pdf}`.

I'd like to replace some text in `img.pdf`. It seems that `psfrag` can do this with `latex`, and there is mention of `pstools` doing this with `pdflatex`, but it seems like `pstools` works with EPS not PDF files.

Is there a way to replace some text in my PDF file?

Comment: Convert the file to eps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Perl script in TeX Live that helps in these cases; it's called `fragmaster`.

You should stop using obsolete commands such as `\epsfig{file=...}`, turning to the better interface of `graphicx`: `\includegraphics[<options>]{<file>}`.